# Drawing dashed border matrix with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-matrix

I need to draw a matrix such that there is dashed line between each column and row. This is my code just to start, but the result is not good. As you see the second horizontal line is not direct and the vertical line does not go to end

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mymatrix) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={(},right
delimiter={)}]
{ A(1)  &  B_{1,2} & B_{1,3}&  \cdots  &  B_{1,r-1} & B_{1,r} \\
    B_{1,2}^T  &  A(2)  &  0 & \cdots &  0  &  0 \\
    B_{1,3}^T &  0  &  A(3)  &  \cdots  &  0 & 0\\
    \vdots & 0 &  0  &   \ddots  &  0  &  0\\
    B_{1,r-1}^T  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0\\
    B_{1,r}^T  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0\\
};
\draw[black,dashed] (mymatrix-1-1.south west) -- (mymatrix-1-6.south east);
\draw[black,dashed] (mymatrix-2-1.south west) -- (mymatrix-2-6.south east);
\draw[black,dashed] (mymatrix-1-4.north east) -- (mymatrix-6-6.north east -| mymatrix-1-4.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a MWE ?

Comment: what is MWE ???

Comment: Click here to know it: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An MWE starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, like this one:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mymatrix) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={(},right
delimiter={)}]
{ A(1)  &  B_{1,2} & B_{1,3}&  \cdots  &  B_{1,r-1} & B_{1,r} \\
    B_{1,2}^T  &  A(2)  &  0 & \cdots &  0  &  0 \\
    B_{1,3}^T &  0  &  A(3)  &  \cdots  &  0 & 0\\
    \vdots & 0 &  0  &   \ddots  &  0  &  0\\
    B_{1,r-1}^T  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0\\
    B_{1,r}^T  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0\\
};
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+1)}]in {1,...,2}
{\path ($(mymatrix-\X-1.south west)!0.5!(mymatrix-\Y-1.north west)$) coordinate
(aux\X);
\draw[black,dashed] (mymatrix.west |- aux\X) -- (mymatrix.east |- aux\X);
}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+1)}]in {1,...,5}
{\path ($(mymatrix-1-\X.east)!0.5!(mymatrix-1-\Y.west)$) coordinate
(auy\X);
\draw[black,dashed] (mymatrix.north -| auy\X) -- (mymatrix.south -| auy\X);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is perfect. thanks. How do you draw vertical lines?

Comment: @Noone Sorry, I was too sloppy, but I added it now.

Comment: I want the vertical for every column. not for a one.

Comment: @Noone Doesn't this contradict with you user name? (Just kidding! ;-)

Comment: Thank you bro, you saved my day. LOL, Did you see Game of Thrones movie? I am that No one guy ;)

Answer (score 1):

For information, `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix` constructs **a matrix of TikZ nodes** and provides tools to draw dashed rules (or rules with other styles of TikZ) in the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{cccc|[tikz=dashed]cc}[margin=3pt]
    A(1)  &  B_{1,2} & B_{1,3}&  \cdots  &  B_{1,r-1} & B_{1,r} \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed]
    B_{1,2}^T  &  A(2)  &  0 & \cdots &  0  &  0 \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed]
    B_{1,3}^T &  0  &  A(3)  &  \cdots  &  0 & 0\\
    \vdots & 0 &  0  &   \ddots  &  0  &  0\\
    B_{1,r-1}^T  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0\\
    B_{1,r}^T  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0\\
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]